# Where are the GAE Backends logs?

Tags: google-app-engine

As soon as I figured out how to invoke my app as a Backends app, my log messages stopped appearing.

I found this helpful [post](http://www.pdjamez.com/2011/05/google-app-engine-backends-part-deux/) which says the Backends logs are kept separately and that I need to switch to Backends view by selecting the named backend from the dropdown at the top of the admin console, but I don't see anything Backends specific in that list to select.

Perhaps this is a clue... when I invoke my app via myapp.appspot.com/dostuff, in the log I see I'm getting the **DeadlineExceededError** after 60 secs, indicating it's not running as a Backends app.  But when I invoke it via **mybackend.myapp.appspot.com/dostuff**, it continues running as needed, but no log entries!

Seems like I'm missing something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow my app wasn't fully recognized by GAE as a Backend app.  And therefore my backend instances weren't available in the drop-list.  Seeing that others had similar trouble with a Python 2.7 app [(ex.)](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6081) that had been initially uploaded as a 2.5 app, I created a new app in GAE and uploaded to there and it worked.  Sorry I don't have a more definitive answer.

Before all was working well, I also ended up creating an empty /_ah/start handler as suggested by someone in this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/4f09be02303a4d8b/859bff2bf2ce38b5?lnk=raot).  Also if you're deploying a multi-threaded backend, make sure to check this [post](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe) out -- there's some important stuff I didn't run across in the docs.